# I'm trying to create a plot using data from a file, however it is not plotting the data into a graph it is only showing the limits

Tags: python, graphing

I am using the first two columns of the file so in python that is 0 and 1. I set up the code for the graph exactly as I have in the past and its giving me this for the output: (3500.0, 7000.0), instead of plotting a graph.

This is the code that I'm using to plot the data.

```
#imports relevant libraries
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#the following code will plot the data
fig = plt.figure() 

#graphs the data into the x and y regions
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.plot(spectra_1[:,0],spectra_1[:,1],'r-', label = 'WN5')
axes.plot(spectra_2[:,0],spectra_2[:,1],'r-', label = 'O5 V')
axes.plot(spectra_3[:,0],spectra_3[:,1],'r-', label = 'O9 V')
axes.plot(spectra_4[:,0],spectra_4[:,1],'r-', label = 'B3 V')
axes.plot(spectra_5[:,0],spectra_5[:,1],'r-', label = 'B9 V')
axes.plot(spectra_6[:,0],spectra_6[:,1],'r-', label = 'A0 V')
axes.plot(spectra_7[:,0],spectra_7[:,1],'r-', label = 'A5 V')
axes.plot(spectra_8[:,0],spectra_8[:,1],'r-', label = 'F2 V')
axes.plot(spectra_9[:,0],spectra_9[:,1],'r-', label = 'F8 V')
axes.plot(spectra_10[:,0],spectra_10[:,1],'r-', label = 'G2 V')
axes.plot(spectra_11[:,0],spectra_11[:,1],'r-', label = 'G8 V')
axes.plot(spectra_12[:,0],spectra_12[:,1],'r-', label = 'K5 V')
axes.plot(spectra_13[:,0],spectra_13[:,1],'r-', label = 'M0 V')
axes.plot(spectra_14[:,0],spectra_14[:,1],'r-', label = 'M6 V')
axes.plot(spectra_15[:,0],spectra_15[:,1],'r-', label = 'L5')

#creates an x and y label for the graph
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (Angstroms)')
plt.ylabel('Normalized Flux')

#the following code will give the graph a title
plt.title('Stellar Flux Profile')

#this will apply a limit to the code to only plot what is in the visible wavelength range
plt.xlim(3500,7000)
```

Comment: Try adding a final statement: `plt.show()`